# Не могу сделать http запрос в Android

Tags: java, android, http

У меня не получается сделать http запрос в Android, код ниже; В манифесте разрешение есть

```
public class WebRequests {
    public String getContent(String http) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        String line = null;
        try {
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(http).openConnection();

            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(250);
            connection.setReadTimeout(250);

            connection.connect();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            if (HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK == connection.getResponseCode()) {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                Log.d("WebReqeust", line);
            } else {
                Log.e("WebRequest", connection.getResponseCode() + ", " + connection.getResponseMessage());
            }
        } catch (Throwable cause) {
            cause.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return line;
    }
}
```

Comment: Какая ошибка? Что в манифесте прописано?

Comment: Вы же знаете, что работа с сетью [запрещена в основном потоке](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException)? Но для верного ответа необходимо описание ошибки

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов, знаю

Comment: @ArtyMorris не в манифесте проблема

Comment: @Slavatar Есть в манифесте секретный ключ

Comment: @ArtyMorris, `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />` - единственное что прописано мною, остальное дефолт

Comment: А разрешение uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" присутствует?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот код запроса погоды

```
    public static JSONObject getWeatherJSON(String lat, String lon){
    String _input = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon;
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(_input);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder(1024);
        String tmp="";
        while(true) {
            try {
                if ((tmp = reader.readLine()) == null) break;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            json.append(tmp).append("\n");
        }
    try {
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONObject data = null;
    try {
        data = new JSONObject(json.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // This value will be 404 if the request was not
        // successful
    try {
        if (data.getInt("cod") != 200){
            return null;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return data;
}
```

плюсом в манифесте прописать

```
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Comment: Я попросил рассказать что не так в моем коде, а не скинуть на его основе рабочий (

Comment: Код мой, я ваш не трогал. Мне кажется разбираться в вашем коде это ваша задача) А наша подсказать

Comment: Почему-то на этом сайте ходит тенденция постить код без комментариев. Это не является полноценным ответом, и в общем-то мало кому помогает. То же самое касается и вопроса, куда выкладывают свой код без описания проблемы и каких-либо попыток их решить.

Comment: А какой комментарий хотелось бы получить? Код практически идентичен тому, что в запросе. И он несложный